# Debug Azure Website with Custom Domain

Tags: c#, azure, ssl, visual-studio-2013

I have a website configured on Azure. I also purchased & installed a SSL Certificate from Comodo for it along with a custom domain.

I want to debug my websites on the custom domain and not on the *.azurewebsites.net subdomain.

I'm using VS2013 and I have Remote Debugging enabled via the Azure portal. So everything *seems* to be configured correctly.

But when I attach the debugger to my website I this error:

[image]

Am I doing something wrong or have I incorrectly configured something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SSL is preventing it from communicating with debugger.  How we overcame it in my last project was because we were using test data we left adding the SSL till we pushed to production.

Comment: Yup, figured that out right now. Had to disable SSL for Debugging purposes.